# After being disconnected from a running job, how to show logs again in Google Cloud SDK Shell?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stdout, google-cloud-ml

I'm running a job on Google's Machine Learning Engine. I issued this job from the Google Cloud SDK Shell on Windows. At some point, I closed my laptop and lost connection to Google Cloud. The job kept running on Google's servers in the mean time. Now that I have reopened my laptop and got connected to the internet again, the shell has output:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.ml-engine.jobs.submit.training) There was a problem refreshing your current auth tokens: Unable to find the server at www.googleapis.com
Please run: 

$gcloud auth login

to obtain new credentials.
```

So I ran that command. The browser opened, I clicked on my Google account and authenticated. Then I saw:

```
You are now logged in as [my Google e-mail address].
Your current project is [None]. You can change this setting by running:

$ gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID
```

I did that also, and then saw the output:

```
Updated property [core/project].
```

So everything seems to work. Online, in the Google Cloud Console, I can view the logs of my job while it is running. However, my question is, is it possible to get those logs/stdout to be printed in my shell again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like what is explained in this [documentation page about ML Engine logging](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/troubleshooting#finding_the_logs).

You can either use the logging service specifying your preferred filter, with [`gcloud beta logging read`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/logging/read) or, in order to print ML Engine job logs in the console, you can use this ML Engine-specific command, with the options and flags you need, in order to print the logs of your job:

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs stream-logs
```

You can find the reference for that command in [this other page](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ml-engine/jobs/stream-logs).